# How do I sum values based on criteria in the same row?

Tags: google-sheets

How do I sum values horizontally that match the word "food" in cell A1.

Example below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`SUM` ignores strings so you can simply use `SUM(E1:1)` to add up all the cells in the first row. No need to check whether they fall under "FOOD" since all the "FOOD" is already arranged.

Comment: If the tables will be in a different order, then please share a copy that includes realistic data.

Comment: sorry, I wanted it to be dynamic is there a way?

Comment: It should be. @tuah can you provide a link to a copy of your google sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a few `VLOOKUP()` formulas:

`=sum({VLOOKUP("FOOD", A1:B4, 2,0),VLOOKUP("FOOD", D1:E4, 2,0),VLOOKUP("FOOD", G1:H4, 2,0),VLOOKUP("FOOD", J1:K4, 2,0)})`

Just change each range to the different ranges of your tables. You can also add or remove `VLOOKUP()` formulas as needed, just make sure to follow the same formatting.

Here is an example of this working in an example sheet I made:

[image: ex]

Please let me know if you have any issues with this